# how to have a three-dimensional table in gams?

Tags: gams-math

I have a table with an index of rows and then the columns grouped in different blocks in csv, like this:

```
      scenario 1           scenario 2                  scenario 3
     dog cat mouse         dog   cat mouse            dog cat mouse
```

1
2
3
...

I don't know if there is a way for gams to read the csv and interpret it so that I can then use the data in equations.